# Selecting rows in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How do I make it so my code selects the rows in the data grid view that they click rather than hard coding it into the code itself, I want to select each row that the user selects with the mouse on the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set multiselect to true for your DataGridView and your dataGridView.SelectionMode should be FullRowSelect

Example:

```
dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
dataGridView.MultiSelect = true;
```

Then you can get the selected rows with

```
Dim selectedItems As DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection = dataGridView.SelectedRows
      For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In selectedItems
            'Add code to handle whatever you want for each row
      Next
End Sub
```